# How to transfer a Spark table from one schema to another?

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, namespaces, schema, delta-lake

Is it possible to transfer a table from one namespace to another namespace in Spark, just like we do change schema of a table in SQL Server via command `ALTER SCHEMA new_schema_name TRANSFER old_schema_name.table_name`, without having to drop and create table again?

I have Spark installed in my local machine.

Comment: Can you please post a sample dataset and the operation you're trying to perform?  Think that will help others.

Answer (score 0):

There are certain schema change operations you can perform without having to drop and create the table again (e.g. when column mapping is enabled, you can drop, reorder, and rename columns via metadata operations).

Here's an example of how to drop a column:

```
ALTER TABLE `my_cool_table` DROP COLUMN language
```

Other operations will require a rewrite of the data, it depends.

Comment: Could you give me a syntax to change Schema (Namespace or Database) of a table instead of dropping a column please, if you have done it before.